# Update em campo de data que atualiza campo calculado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho na minha tabela um campo de DtComportamento do tipo DateTime. Além deste tenho outros três campos computados da seguinte forma:

DIA: (datepart(day,getdate()))

MES: (datepart(month,getdate()))

ANO: (datepart(year,getdate()))

Com base nesta situação eu tenho um problema e uma dúvida:

---

Dúvida:
Como faço para computar os campos com base no DtComportamento? Ou seja, preciso de algo como:

DIA: (datepart(day,DtComportamento))

MES: (datepart(month,DtComportamento))

ANO: (datepart(year,DtComportamento))

---

Problema:
Ao fazer um Update na tabela, o SQL me retorna:

*"A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo."*

Este é o meu Update:

```
UPDATE Comportamentos SET IdAvaliado = 1013, 
                          IdArea = 3, 
                          Nome = 'Auxilia quando solicitado', 
                          Tipo = 1, 
                          Descricao = 'Auxilia os colegas quando solicitado',
                          Nota = 9.5, 
                          DtComportamento = '2015-07-31 16:12' 
WHERE Id = 13
```

---

SQL de Criação da Tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Comportamentos (
  Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  IdAvaliador int NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Colaboradores(Id),
  IdAvaliado int NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Colaboradores(Id),
  IdArea int NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Areas_Comportamento(Id),
  Nome varchar (100) NOT NULL,
  Tipo smallint NOT NULL,
  Descricao varchar (300) NULL,
  Nota decimal (5, 2) NULL,
  Dia AS (datepart(day,getdate())),
  Mes AS (datepart(month,getdate())),
  Ano AS (datepart(year,getdate())),
  DtComportamento datetime NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  DtCadastro datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  Status smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o seu problema é nos campos calculados? De qual tipo sao os seus campos calculados? Se você retira-los da tabela e tentar dar o update, funciona?

Comment: Qual o formato do campo `DtComportamento`?

Comment: Rode esse comando, por favor: (select name from sys.syslanguages
where langid=@@langid). Qual o resultado?

Comment: @cantoni Editei a pergunta e coloquei o script de criação da tabela... se remover os campos calculados da tabela eu faço o update normalmente.

Comment: @LúcioRubens, conforme eu citei na pergunta o campo DtComportamento é do tipo DateTime...

Comment: @cantoni o resultado é Português (Brasil)

Comment: Consegui o update removendo os hífens da data, passando ela como: DtComportamento = '20150731 16:12'. Mas ainda falta os campos calculados com base na DtComportamento e não no getdate()

Comment: Uma forma curta seria: DAY(DtComportamento), MONTH(DtComportamento), YEAR(DtComportamento)

Comment: @LúcioRubens funcionou, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu problema não é nos campos calculados, mas com o formato da Data e a Linguagem do seu banco de dados.

No exemplo da pergunta, o  Update no campo DTComportamentos é:

```
DtComportamento = '2015-07-31 16:12'
```

Porém, no seu comentário, a linguagem do seu banco está Português. Para você fazer o seu update (ou Insert), troque para:

```
DtComportamento = '2015-31-07 16:12'
```

O comando para saber a linguagem do banco é:

```
select name from sys.syslanguages where langid=@@langid
```

O comando para alterar a linguagem (apenas na sessão corrente) é:

```
SET LANGUAGE portuguese
```

**Atualização**:

Para criar campos calcualdos que extraem Dia,Mes e Ano de um campo do tipo DateTime, você pode fazer de duas formas:

Utlizando a função **datepart**:

```
 Dia AS (datepart(day,DtComportamento)),
 Mes AS (datepart(month,DtComportamento)),
 Ano AS (datepart(year,DtComportamento)),
```

Ou como o @LucioRubens disse em seu comentário, utilizando as funções DAY,MONTH e YEAR diretamente:

```
 Dia AS (DAY(DtComportamento)),
 Mes AS (MONTH(DtComportamento)),
 Ano AS (YEARDtComportamento)),
```